# unique deposit address for each investor in ico

Tags: contract-development, tokens, ico

How can I create a unique deposit/contribution address for each investor in ICO. Is it possible to do it for both BTC and ETH ?. How can funds be transferred to one mutisig wallet from each unique address. Is there a way to achieve this using the smart contract ?

Answer (score 0):

Each investor should already have a wallet, which already consists of a unique address. Funds can simply be sent to their wallet address.

You can achieve transfer from one ETH address to another using smart contract contracts which are programmed in solidity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in my question. I meant how can I show a unique address to each investor where they send ETH or BTC to participate. ?.e.g You and I participate in a crowdsale but the address I have to send ETH to is different from yours and all other participants.

Comment: In general, when you deploy a ETH smart contract that contract will have a a unique address. This is the address that will handle your crowdsale distribute tokens etc.. You cannot (currently) easily do smart contracts with BTC.

Comment: Does that mean you and I will have see the same address where we have to send ETH ?. How can the addresses we see be different and unique for us ?